# point domain to vps

Tags: linux, dns, vps, nameservers

New to Server Administration, we all have to start somewhere.

I have been using shared hosting for years but i am trying out a VPS.

I purchased a VPS for 4 months trial with a single IP
Installed Webmin and Virtualmin on the server.

I have several domains with 123-reg.co.uk and godaddy.com but hosting with another company.
I want to leave the domains managed by these companies but change the hosting to my new VPS on SOME domains.

Now the VPS does not have a domain attached and only has a single IP

So my question, how do I configure domains so I can change the nameserver to point to my new server? (Setting up a DNS Server) as you would for any hosting company.

Regards

Jamie

Answer (score 3):

You need to set up an A record on the domain to point to your VPS IP address.

In 123-reg go to 'manage domain' and you can edit the DNS records there.

Edit: if your VPS host provides DNS hosting then you can point the nameservers to them but as you said you want to keep the domains managed by the domain company then follow my suggestion above.

Comment: In addition to this answer, look into virtual hosts if you want to point multiple domain names to your VPS and expect it to handle that properly.